# Bases for space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm facing an exercise to determine basis for some spaces of polynomials. Here they are

> Consider the space of polynomials of degree equal or less than 3
>
> $U =${$p(t) \in \mathbb{R_3}[t]$ | $p(0)=0$}
>
> $U =${$p(t) \in \mathbb{R_3}[t]$ | $p(1)=0$}
>
> $U =${$p(t) \in \mathbb{R_3}[t]$ | $p(0)=p(1)$}

So my answer was $(x^3,x^2,x)$ for the first one $(x^3-1,x^2-1,x-1$) for the second one and $(x^3-x, x^2-x, 1)$ for the last one.
When I checked the key for this question I found out they erased the vectors with $x^3$...

Can someone explain me why?

I tried to write my vectors in vectores of coordinates through the canonical basis and then apply Gauss elimination but I didn't reach to linearly dependent vectors so I think we can't erase one, can we?

Thanks!

Comment: The mentioned subspaces are all $3$-dimensional and certainly a polynomial of degree $3$ must belong to a basis. Unless you misinterpreted the notation and they meant the space of polynomials of degree *less* than $3$.

Comment: It says in the original question "equal or less"

Comment: Complain… $\quad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps $f,g,h\colon \mathbb{R}_3[x]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{align}
f(p)&=p(0)\\
g(p)&=p(1)\\
h(p)&=p(1)-p(0)
\end{align}
are easily seen to be linear and surjective. So their kernels (null spaces) have dimension $3$. The kernels are precisely the subspaces you have to find bases of, in the same order.

Since clearly all three subspaces contain polynomials of degree $3$ (and you found them), a bases for each of them *must* contain a polynomial of degree $3$.

---

Your solution is, as far as I can see, correct, but let's check it.

The first set is clearly contained in $\ker f$ and also linearly independent. The second set is contained in $\ker g$ and the matrix of coordinates with respect to the basis $\{x^3,x^2,x,1\}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that's easily seen to have rank $3$, so the set is linearly independent.

The third set is contained in $\ker h$ and the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that has rank $3$.